# How to databind a DependencyObject is SL4 in code behind?

Tags: .net, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I saw that SL4 support binding on DependencyObject rather than FrameworkElement... This works fine in xaml, however I need to do that in code behind.

However I don't see any method "SetBinding" in the DependencyObject class, how can I do ?

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the BindingOperations.SetBinding() method.